# Scan webpage for text changes and content

Tags: python, scanning

New to programming. If this is too basic I do apologize.

As a more complex project to hone my budding skills with I am trying to build a price scanner and reporting feature that waits for new text on a webpage such as sale,discount,etc and read the price and send that information back to me.

Can you help me get pointed in the right direction?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need to do some research on scraping.

Some trainings and books that you may be interested to go deeper:

- [Data Scraping and Data Mining from Beginner to Pro with Python](https://learning.oreilly.com/videos/data-scraping-and/9781801818483/)
- [Python Web Scraping Cookbook](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/python-web-scraping/9781787285217/)